# Derivation of the Equation for Constraint Forces

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics

How do we derive the relationship $$F_\text{constraint}=\displaystyle\sum_i \lambda_i\nabla g_i$$ where $g$ is the constraint function, from the following relationship? $$\frac  d {d\epsilon}S|_{\epsilon=0} = \int\frac d {d\epsilon} L(q,\dot q,t)|_{\epsilon=0}\ dt \stackrel{!}= \displaystyle\sum_i\lambda_i \nabla g_i$$

Here, we are using the method of finding an extremal point of a scalar valued function on a constraint using the method of Lagrange multipliers, but I cannot derive the relationship for $F_\text{constraint}$ from this equation, and frankly I don't really see why the relationship for the constraint forces should be true. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: it is the constant of deviation from the path that makes $S$ stationary: for given boundary points $t_1$ and $t_2$, we observe the family of paths $q(t)$ that satisfy the boundaries. we are looking for the path that makes $S$ stationary (extremal). we can write $q(t)$ as  $q=q_0+\epsilon \eta$, where $q_0$ is the path that we are searching for, and $\eta$ is the deviation paths. in order to find the extremal of $S$, which is now a function of $\epsilon$, we set $\frac d {d\epsilon}S\stackrel{!}=0$, which by definition is fulfilled when $\epsilon=0$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to far. The functional/Gateaux derivative of your action (**without lagrange multiplier**) is the usual Euler-Lagrange equation. Thus:
$$ \dfrac{\delta S}{\delta x_j(t)}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x_j} - \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i}\lambda_i \dfrac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$$

(I might have changed the sign of the Lagrange multiplier to make thing easier, but it's simply a matter of convention). Let's assume that your Lagrangian is of the form $L=K-U$ (simply to help with the understanding, it's not required of course..). Then, the previous equation gives you:

$$\dfrac{d p_j}{dt}= -\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x_j} + \sum_{i}\lambda_i \dfrac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$$ If you replace the indices by gradient and vector --something you should be careful about in your first equation-- the result is definitively of the form:

$$\dfrac{d \vec p}{dt} = \vec F_{conservative} + \vec F_{constraint}$$